# Angular2 Firebase Authentication is not working,

Tags: javascript, angular, angularfire2

My app.module.ts is like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
    import {RouterModule,Routes} from '@angular/router';
    import { AngularFireModule, AuthProviders, AuthMethods } from 'angularfire2';
    import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
    import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from "angularfire2/database";

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './Components/home/home.component';
    import { ListingComponent } from './Components/listing/listing.component';
    import { ListingsComponent } from './Components/listings/listings.component';
    import { AddListingComponent } from './Components/add-listing/add-listing.component';
    import { EditListingComponent } from './Components/edit-listing/edit-listing.component';
    import { NavbarComponent } from './Components/navbar/navbar.component';
    import { FirebaseService } from "app/Services/firebase.service";


     export const firebaseConfig = 
     {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyDiPNutY-Bon3id4Oowqj0mTeFQkKacHeo",
        authDomain: "proplisting-6bdac.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://proplisting-6bdac.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "proplisting-6bdac",
        storageBucket: "proplisting-6bdac.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "383202658531"
      };

      const firebaseAuthConfig={
       provider:AuthProviders.Google,
       method:AuthMethods.Popup
      };

      const appRoutes:Routes=[
        {path:'', component:HomeComponent},
        {path:'listings',component:ListingsComponent},
        {path:'add-listing',component:AddListingComponent}

      ]

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ListingComponent,
        ListingsComponent,
        AddListingComponent,
        EditListingComponent,
        NavbarComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        AngularFireDatabaseModule,
        AngularFireAuthModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig, firebaseAuthConfig),
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
      ],
      providers: [FirebaseService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

It is showing the error as

> ERROR in C:/AngularFirebase/proplisting/src/app/app.module.ts (6,29): Module '"C:/AngularFirebase/proplisting/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AuthProviders'.
>   C:/AngularFirebase/proplisting/src/app/app.module.ts (6,44): Module '"C:/AngularFirebase/proplisting/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AuthMethods'.
>   C:/AngularFirebase/proplisting/src/app/app.module.ts (57,53): Argument of type '{ provider: any; method: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
>
> ERROR in C:/AngularFirebase/proplisting/src/app/app.module.ts (6,29): Module '"C:/AngularFirebase/proplisting/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AuthProviders'.
>   C:/AngularFirebase/proplisting/src/app/app.module.ts (6,44): Module '"C:/AngularFirebase/proplisting/node_modules/angularfire2/index"' has no exported member 'AuthMethods'.
>   C:/AngularFirebase/proplisting/src/app/app.module.ts (57,53): Argument of type '{ provider: any; method: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
>   webpack: Failed to compile.

Comment: Please include a clear question when you post on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to import members that don't exist in the package `angularfire2`.

It might be because you are not following the latest documentation or the latest `angularfire2` version.

The new documentation for **AngularFire 2.4** can be found [**here**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/tree/master/docs) and for **AngularFireAuth** in [**here**](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md).

Your "question" doesn't really have a question in it, you are just saying you have errors, so I assumed you want to fix it by changing your imports to work on the latest API.

**From their migration guide ([Link](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-4-upgrade.md)):**

> Removing AngularFire for Modularity
>
> Prior to 4.0, AngularFire2 did not take advantage of the Firebase
>   SDK's modularity for tree shaking. The AngularFire service has now
>   been removed and the library broken up into smaller @NgModules:
>
> - AngularFireModule
> - AngularFireDatabaseModule
> - AngularFireAuthModule

That's probably the primary cause of your errors.

So I suggest you take a look at their docs, they really had a clear and good explanation of the migration process.
I'm not going to copy everything from there to here.

Comment: @Pranav please consider accepting the answer if you think that helped :)